# datetime64[ns] column on export is displayed as DATE datatype in Oracle DB

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oracle, dataframe, sqlalchemy

In my dataframe, I've a column called 'DateStamp' which shows today date as **2021-09-10 00:19:57.593350**

```
final_df['DateStamp'] = pd.to_datetime('today')
```

However, when I export the dataframe to my Oracle Database, the DateStamp column is created with DATA_TYPE as DATE instead of timestamp

```
dtyp2 = {c:types.VARCHAR(final_df_toDB[c].str.len().max())
    ...:         for c in final_df_toDB.columns[final_df_toDB.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}

final_df_toDB.to_sql('sample_table',engine_conn, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=dtyp2)
```

and because of this, my Oracle Table only shows the Date Part of the timestamp. However, I'd like the column show entire datestamp

Comment: I see that you are already familiar with the `dtype=` argument to `to_sql()` (although you don't show what you're passing). That would be the way to fix the problem, but note that if the table already exists you'll need to change the column type yourself (`to_sql()` can't do that for you).

Comment: @GordThompson I have added the dtype part of the code in the question, I'm currently using it to convert my object columns to VARCHAR, can you suggest how I can use the same variable to convert my date column being parsed as datetime for oracle DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In oracle, a DATE is actually date and time, down to the second.  The *display format* of a DATE is under the control of the client, and most default to only presenting the date, but the time component is still there:

```
SQL> select sysdate default_format,
  2         to_char(sysdate,'dd-Mon-yyyy') dateonly,
  3         to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss') timeonly,
  4         to_char(sysdate,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') date_time
  5  from dual
  6  ;

DEFAULT_F DATEONLY             TIMEONLY DATE_TIME
--------- -------------------- -------- -----------------------------
09-SEP-21 09-Sep-2021          14:15:19 09-Sep-2021 14:15:19

1 row selected.
```